# Which translation programs work well with LaTeX?

Tags: translate, translations, locale

I have to manage the translation of existing Word documents with a translation agency. I want to have them work with LaTeX and I want to convert the Word documents into LaTeX format for better diffing.

They said it would be possible but the first result was rather disappointing since they translated also some keywords which require manual work to reset the keywords.

What is a good way dealing with this issue? I was thinking about providing a list of keywords (all starting with `\`) to avoid the translation of these.

Anyone got experience which translation program to recommend?

Comment: In ConTeXt you have `translate` module. Could you detail a little bit more about what you intend to do. May be a complete example.

Comment: Perhaps consider using markdown instead. Translators could have a quick markdown tutorial and you can convert to Latex afterwards.

Comment: You could suggest using any text editor with syntax highlighting (Notepad++ if they are stuck on Windows, TeXStudio, gedit, you name it). Tell them to translate regular text only (everything that was _not_ marked as special text with colouring).

Comment: All text shall be translated (automatically using translation software of which I do not know the name yet) from English to other languages like German, Italien, French, ...). It will be translated automatically. Getting the name of the translation program would make things easier. Maybe someone is a translator and knows a program that does the task. Of course is proof-reading afterwards necessary. Any Google Translator API tool known?